# grep - Match paths with leading space in file

Tags: regex, linux, grep

Trying to match paths that lead to scripts in a file.
Paths all start with a space so like this:

```
bla bla    
23 01 * * 2,3,4,5,6 /folder/folder/script.sh
bla bla    
23 01 * * 2,3,4,5,6 /folder/folder/folder/script2.sh
```

I got this so far:

```
grep -o "^[[:space:]].*\.sh" fullList.txt
```

It gets lines with scripts but not just path.
How would I return just paths like this:

```
/folder/folder/script.sh
/folder/folder/folder/script2.sh
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try `grep -oE "(/[^/]*)+\.sh" fullList.txt`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Catches /5 * * * * /folder/folder/script.sh

Comment: Do you mean there can be no space in the path? Then use `"/[^[:space:]]+\.sh"` pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is crontab format (`man 5 crontab`), we can just ignore the first 5 columns:

```
awk '{ $1=$2=$3=$4=$5=""; print; }'
```

Since you might have comments in your crontab, you need to get rid of those, too:

```
grep -v '^\s*#'
```

Putting it together:

```
grep -v '^\s*#' fullList.txt | awk '{ $1=$2=$3=$4=$5=""; print; }'
```

Comment: c'mon, you don't need grep at all ;-) right? `awk '!/^#/{$1....; print; }' file`. Good luck to all.